# Complete weighted graph where every cycle is null-length

Tags: graph-theory

I have a complete edge-weighted digraph, where the length of every cycle is null, ie. the sum of edges' weights is null. I can see that on each edge the weight in one direction is the opposite of the other one, but it is not particularly useful.

Does this type of graph have a name? Are there interesting properties, beside the ones induced by the completion?

For example, in a somehow similar situation in fluid mechanics, under "classic" hypothésis : $\oint_S \vec{v}.\vec{n}dS=0$ implies $\nabla.v=0$.

NB : the weights are elements from $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$, but any relation with scalar weights is more than welcome since it could probably be transposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You've almost answered your own question: you can pick any vertex $v$ and assign it a "potential" $0$, i.e., define a function $p$ with 
$$
p(v) = 0
$$
Now for any vertex $w$, you can define $p(w)$ to be the sum of the weights along *any* directed path from $v$ to $w$. (You can choose *any* path because of your cycle condition, just as in the fluid dynamics case.)

This defines a "potential" $p$ on the entire graph, with the weight between any two adjacent vertices $P$ and $Q$ being $p(Q) - p(P)$.

I'm not sure what graph theorists call such a graph, but I'd personally be inclined to call it a "gradient" graph, and would start almost every proof with the words "Let $p$ be a potential for the graph $G$; then ..."

Apparently such things (even in the case where $G$ is not a complete graph) are called 'potential difference graphs' is electrical engineering; that's hardly surprising, I guess.

Comment: N.B.: the potential (just like the electric potential in a circuit) is only defined up to a  constant: you could add "17" to the potential at every vertex and have a new potential. In that sense, what I've done is a lot like computing an indefinite integral. Perhaps "integrable" would be a good name for such graphs as well, but it doesn't appear to be in common use.

Comment: The analogy you make with an electrical circuit is clever, as my weights are in fact functions, and some of them actually behave like resistors, capacitors, inductor, generators or wires. Thank you very much!